# Sort names from sql to categories in A-Z order

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to print a names from sql on php page and sort it in categoris
My rows:

```
1 anna
2 alena
3 benny
4 dolev
5 niv
```

I want to print it like this:

```
A
alena
anna

B
benny

D
dolev

N
niv
```

EDIT:
I tried

```
while($row_keke = mysql_fetch_array($result_skey002))
{
    $name = $row_keke['name2'];

    if (in_array($name[0], $heb_a_z)) {
    echo $name[0]."<br />".$name."<br /><br />";
    }
}
```

But you see what the problem with this ..
Thanks for everybody .. ! :)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
$lastFirst = '';

while($row_keke = mysql_fetch_array($result_skey002))
{

  $name = $row_keke['name2'];

  if($name[0] != $lastFirst){
     echo "<br />".strtoupper($name[0])."<br />";
     $lastFirst = $name[0];
  }

  echo $name."<br />";

}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should achieve the result you're looking for.

Comment: Great, if it answers your question completely please consider marking it as the answer.  :)  If it does not, let me know what else I can do to help.

*Edit: thanks! :)  Let me know if I can help more.